# WAMP/Zend Framework - How do I setup Zend Framework and how do I reference it in a project?

Tags: php, zend-framework, wamp

I'll admit, Zend Framework is a bit advanced and I want to learn it.  Right now I am taking on a large project that will need MVC, quite frankly because I want to organize the project in an MVC paradigm.

**Overall Question**

*My question is very simply, for anyone who has succeeded with Zend Framework startup, what do I need to do under Windows to get this setup under WAMP server and under an entirely new project.*

Here is what I have done so far.

**1) Grabbed Zend Framework Latest from**

http://framework.zend.com/downloads/latest

**2) Searched for zf.bat online and grabbed a copy**

**2.1) Modified lines within batch file**

```
SET PHP_BIN=C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\php.exe
SET PHP_DIR=C:\wamp\bin\php
```

**3) Modified Zend Framework include path in php.ini of WAMP**

```
include_path = ".;c:\php\includes;c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\zend_framework\library"
```

**4) Downloaded zftool.phar from**

https://packages.zendframework.com/zftool.phar

**4.1) Installed composer using the procedure on the link below**

https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-windows

```
> php composer.phar install
> composer install
```

**Extra Steps) I even tried to run zf tools and I get the standard following message**

> In order to run the zf command, you need to ensure that Zend Framework is inside your include_path.

What steps am I missing?

Comment: After reading the title I came in to downvote the question but you clearly have made an effort and asked a (rare) good question. Upvote earned. Good luck.

Comment: John, for your kind remarks, I am up-voting your comment!  Thank you for the feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're mixing and matching installation instructions for ZF1 and ZF2. For ZF2, since you've already got Composer setup, follow the instructions at the top here: http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/user-guide/skeleton-application.html to get a project started. You don't need to do most of the steps in your question.

Comment: Tim, thank you for the response.  I am looking at the link for the skeleton application now.

Comment: Following the steps on the link, I ran the command within my application directory in c:/wamp/www/RAIL_Dashboard (RAIL_Dashboard is my app folder).  The command I ran was "composer create-project -s c:/wamp/www/RailDashboard"  within the app directory RailDashboard in command prompt.   I now have new directories in my folder.    I am looking to create the MVC directories in my app.  Hopefully creating the MVC directories is this straightforward, and if not, I will create them based on the Zend Framework recommendations manually.